# How does SAS pick reference group when using CLASS statement?

Tags: reference, sas, logistic-regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

How does SAS pick reference group when using CLASS statement?
I have a categorical variable and it can take on about 200 different values. Is it good practice to create dummies for only specific characteristics of this variable? I know that the other values are rarely used and in a correlation analysis they are not significant in predicting Y. The example is: There are about 200 different add-ons and the outcome variable is Sale (success vs. no success) the model is a logistic regression. I want to see whether any of these add ons seem to be more popular among customers and therefore are more likely to lead to a sale. Other IV are: how much the customer already pays on a monthly basis, where the customer comes from and which location the sales agent comes from.

Comment: How many observations do you have. A rough rule of thumb is 25 obs per predictor, so with 199 variables (minimum) you would need, 199*25 = 4975 observations to start off with. If you have a lot of small groups, that are homogeneous you could consider combining some of them.

Answer (score 0):

> How does SAS pick reference group when using CLASS statement?

By default, the first value in sort order is picked as the reference variable.  This can be changed with the `ref=` option.

```
class var(ref='B')
```

> Is it good practice to create dummies for only specific
>   characteristics of this variable?

That's a question better asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)